# Python syntax / understanding

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, counting

```
def counting_sort(array, maxval):
    """in-place counting sort"""
    m = maxval + 1
    count = [0] * m               # init with zeros
    for a in array:
        count[a] += 1             # count occurences
    i = 0
    for a in range(m):            # emit
        for c in range(count[a]): # - emit 'count[a]' copies of 'a' #CONFUSED
            array[i] = a
            i += 1
    return array

print counting_sort( [1, 4, 7, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 3, 2, 1], 7 )
#            prints: [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 7]
```

So in the code above i dont understand the line I marked with confused, 4 lines before the last. 
Might be because I am new to python or just stupid.

1. What happends in the first case? When the range is [ ] ? ... "for each c in the range of empty array....?
2. i dont get `array[i] = a` on the line under aswell. If a is the first element in the counting array which might be zero, how can it be added....? Really confused...

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You've apparently figured out that `count[a]` will be 0, and that `range(count[a])` will therefore be `[]`.

So, what you're asking is, what does this do:

```
for i in []:
   do_stuff(i)
```

The answer is that it loops over each of the 0 elements—in other words, it doesn't loop at all. It just does nothing.*

This is explained in the docs for [the `for` statement](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement):

> … The suite is then executed once for each item provided by the iterator… **When the items are exhausted (which is immediately when the sequence is empty…)** … the loop terminates.

---

And that implicitly explains your second bit of confusion:

> If a is the first element in the counting array which might be zero, how can it be added

When `count[a]` is 0, you will never get into the loop, so that case cannot ever arise.

---

* If the `for` statement has an `else` clause, it does run the `else` clause.

Answer (score 0):

1. `range` will give you a list with specified start and end values. For example

   ```
   print range(5)
   ```

   will print

   ```
   [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
   ```

   When you say, `range(m)` or `range(count[a])` it will generate a list till `m` or `count[a]` starting from 0.
2. About `array[i] = a`

   In the `range(m)`, for each element, the code checks the `count[a]`. If the `count[a]` is 0, the second loop will not be executed. (`range(0)` will produce an empty list) So, for when `a` is 0  `array[i] = a` will not be executed.

Answer (score 0):

I simplified part of you code, maybe it it can help you understand the core of the algorithm well . After counting all the elements in the array, we can reconstruct  a sorted array only with the information stored in `count[]`.

```
array=[]
for a in range(m): 
    array.extend([a]*count[a])
```